# Let me know when you were free

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-construction, let

Is this sentence construction grammatically correct?

> Let me know when you were free.

Comment: I assume you mean what Maulik V thinks you mean. But, for what it's worth, the line sounds very poetic the way you wrote it. It sounds like it may be a lyric from a song. It's still incorrect English though. :) By the way, drop the second "is" from your question.

Answer (score 1):

No! It should be...

> Let me know when you **are/will be** free.

Here, the word *let* is used as to notify you when something happens in future (here, when that person is free). The verb *were* refers to past where future notification cannot happen in this context.

Comment: Inspector to a murder suspect : `Where were you between 8-9 pm on xyz day?`, Suspect : `I've to look in my journal for that, it's at my home`. Inspector : `Let us know where you were during that period`. Not ok?

Comment: @SparKotॐ Possible but then why dig rarest rare condition that even OP might not have thought? Ask yourself (without thinking every possibility in the language) what fits there? Let me know when you were/are free? The simple proof is... you had to built a story justifying *were* whereas if I put *are*, the sentence is quite clear.

Comment: @MaulikV "when you will be free". The meaning of this  sentence is asking the person when he/she will become free? for eg after sometime, or tommorrow . Is my understanding correct